# Nested Confirm Pop Ups not working

Tags: jquery

I want to display one more same confirmation pop on click of YES button but that is not working, My code is :

```
$.confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete ?"
    confirm: function() { 
        $.confirm({
            text: "We are going to delete ?"
            confirm: function() { 

            },
            cancel: function() {

            }
        });
    },
    cancel: function() {

    }
});
```

I'm using jquery-confirm.js for this.

I need some alternative to implement this functionality or solution for this problem.

Comment: You are missing a comma after the value of text property.

Answer (score 2):

You need first close or hide the first "confirm", then open the second "confirm".

```
$.confirm({
    text: "Question 1?",
    confirm: function(button) {
        $('.confirmation-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $.confirm({
              text: "Question 2?",
              confirm: function() {
                // do something 
              },
              cancel: function() {
                // do something else
              }
            });
        });
    },
    cancel: function() {
        // nothing to do
    }
})
```

Comment: The same line of code is also posted to an issue on the plugin's Git page: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:SvtpoJMemugJ:https://github.com/myclabs/jquery.confirm/issues/54+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk - glad to see there's an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

As @pmandell said, your configuration object is invalid. You need commas after each attribute of the JavaScript object like so:

```
$.confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete ?",
    confirm: function() { 
        $.confirm({
            text: "We are going to delete ?",
            confirm: function() { 

            },
            cancel: function() {

            }
        });
    },
    cancel: function() {

    }
 });
```